# whereBetween not working as expected when chaining in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have a `user_orders` table and  `an User -> hasMany() -> Orders`:

```
id  | user_id |      date 
123 |  12345  |   2024-02-01   
124 |  12345  |   2024-02-02
125 |  12345  |   2024-02-03
126 |  45678  |   2024-02-01 
127 |  45678  |   2024-02-03
```

I want to find the user who has the order for **every day** between `$startDate` and `$endDate`. For example, when `$startDate = 2024-02-01` and `$endDate = 2024-02-03` only the `user_id = 12345` should be returned, whereas the `user_id = 45678` shouldn't because this user does not have a order for `2024-02-02`.
My question is, why is `whereBetween` not working anymore if placed inside the chaining function?

```
// not working as both user 12345 and 45678 are returned
User::whereHas('Orders', function ($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
        $query->where('some conditions')
              ->orWhere(function($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
                   $query->whereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate])
                         ->groupBy('user_id')
                         ->havingRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT date) = ? ', [diffInDays($startDate, $endDate)]) 
              });
}
```

```
// working, correctly returns only user 12345
User::whereHas('Orders', function ($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
         $query->where('some conditions')
               ->orWhereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate])
               ->groupBy('user_id')
                ->havingRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT date) = ? ', [diffInDays($startDate, $endDate)]) 
}
```

Comment: what are you expecting to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: @lagbox I've edited the question with example again, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the First Query, The groupBy and havingRaw clauses are inside the orWhere closure and will only be applied when the orWhere condition is met, which might not be the case for all relevant rows.

Now, lets take the example for user_id = **45678** by looking into the following conditions as you commented for the example.

> **some conditions** are false, **whereBetween** is true:

In this case, **groupBy** and **havingRaw** will be applied. But since **user_id = 45678** doesn’t have an order for every day in the range, it should not be included. However, because **some conditions** failed, this user might still be included.

> Both **some conditions** and **whereBetween** are true:

In this scenario, the user might be included correctly based on the **groupBy** and **havingRaw** conditions.

> **some conditions** are true, **whereBetween** is false:

The user will be included based on the **some conditions** regardless of the **whereBetween** clause.

The Second Query is working because that the whereBetween is directly chained with the where clause, and the groupBy and havingRaw clauses are applied to the whole query, not conditionally. This makes the query more straightforward and ensures that the grouping and having clauses are always applied.

The first Query should be written like this,

```
User::whereHas('Orders', function ($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
    $query->where(function($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
       $query->where('some conditions')
            ->orWhereBetween('date', [$startDate, $endDate]);
    })
    ->groupBy('user_id')
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(DISTINCT date) = ? ', [diffInDays($startDate, $endDate)]);
});
```

Comment: Can you give me an example for the first query? As far as I can see the `conditions` (`groupBy`, and `havingRaw`) in the first query are only applied when the initial conditions in the outer `where` fail, but I can't figure out why as `user_id = 45678 ` seems always fail the outer `where` condition

Comment: okay I will give an example by updating the answer